# "Weird" footnote bibliography demand

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my thesis and my supervisor asked me to create a pretty "weird" bibliography style (well, maybe it's normal to some of you, but for me it's really strange). So, he asked me to cite the author in the paragraph and at the same time, create a footnote with the full bibliography of the paper (see the example).

In the example, you will see there is an in-paragraph citation of Einstein (1906)'s paper and a footnote containing the full bibliography of the paper (Note that the bibliography appears also on the References section).

I did some research on the internet and know that we can you biblatex package to create footcite. However, I cannot create the footcite and in-paragraph cite at the same time. In the example, I had to mannually input the author-year citation (of course, in my thesis, there are many citation and I cannot keep track of all the citations by manual method).

I would like to know if there is any systematic method to cite in both styles ?

```
  \RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{enistein,
      title={On the theory of brownian movement},
      author={Enistein, A},
      journal={Ann. d. Phys},
      volume={19},
      pages={371},
      year={1906}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=authoryear ,
    backend=bibtex,
    style=verbose
    ]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{bib.bib} %Imports bibliography file

    \begin{document}
    \section{First section}
    \vfill
    The paper of Enistein (1906) \footcite{enistein}

    \medskip

    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I sure hope your thesis supervisor isn't forcing you to write "Enistein"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use the `authoryear` style and modify its `cite` macro to print a `\footfullcite` for the source as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \footfullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code as posted requires `biblatex` 3.8 or newer (it can be modified to work with older versions). It also uses Biber as backend, but can be used with BibTeX if that is absolutely necessary.

---

If you want a shorter footnote, you can replace `\footfullcite` by a more specific set of commands, for example

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \mkbibfootnote{%
    \def\blx@delimcontext{bib}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Moewe: Thank you for your assistance. I would like to ask for another favor, if it is possible. I tried to change the footcite into a shorter version (which includes only authors, year and the paper) for a few days, but I got no luck. Can you show me how to modify the above code?

Comment: @DB225681 What do you mean by 'and the paper'? Do you just want author, year and title ("Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998): 'Comparison of methods ...'")? Or do you want more?

Comment: Yes, I would like only the author, year and the title of the paper in the footcite (for example, Andres, J., Domenech, R. & Fatas, A. (2008). "The stabilizing role of government size".)

Comment: @DB225681 I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: @DB225681 See the edited version.

Comment: Moewe: Thank you for your assistance. It works flawlessly.